# Image filter in C

Tags: algorithms

While doing image filter, I was perplexed on a particular topic regarding it. I was wondering how to take the weighted average of the immediate neighboring elements of a 2D array.

I am doing this by taking two matrices and multiplying the immediate neighbors of a first matrix with the elements of the second matrix,

*My approach*:

```
for (int i=1;i<m+1;i++){
   for(int j=1;j<n+1;j++){
      matrix3[i-1][j-1] =
         ((matrix1[i-1][j-1]*matrix2[i-1][j-1])
         +(matrix1[i-1][j]  *matrix2[i-1][j])
         +(matrix1[i-1][j+1]*matrix2[i-1][j+1])
         +(matrix1[i]  [j-1]*matrix2[i]  [j-1])
         +(matrix1[i]  [j]  *matrix2[i]  [j])
         +(matrix1[i]  [j+1]*matrix2[i]  [j+1])
         +(matrix1[i+1][j-1]*matrix2[i+1][j-1])
         +(matrix1[i+1][j]  *matrix2[i+1][j])
         +(matrix1[i+1][j+1]*matrix2[i+1][j+1])
         )/sum;
    }
}
```

*where `sum` is the sum of all the immediate neighbors of an element*

I am just a beginner here, but I think my approach is too much complicated and quite unnecessary.
Is there a simple way of approaching this?

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here.  I don't know why you have rejected your approach.  If you want to ask a question about it, is there some specific requirement that your approach violates, or some metric you want to use to evaluate answers?  "Complicated" and "unnecessary" seem subjective to me; and your approach already seems quite simple to me.

Comment: What exactly is *perplexing* you? If weights are two values, only, one for axis-parallel neighbours, one for "diagonal" ones, this approach seems open for one more direction of improvement. There got to be introductions to filtering "two-dimensional samples", and coding that.

Comment: (`all the immediate neighbors of an element` in *which* matrix? (While I think I see *one remote reason* why to assign the result to index $i-1,j-1$, the code should not leave a reader/maintenance programmer guessing.))

Comment: (Two resources to look at are [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) and [Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/ipp.html).)